# Parallel computing in Python Similar to MATLAB

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have been using parfor in MATLAB to run parallel for loops for quite some time. I need to do something similar in Python but I cannot find any simple solution. This is my code:

```
t = list(range(1,3,1))
G = list(range(0,3,2))
results = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['tau', 'p_value','G','t_i'],index=range(0,len(G)*len(t)))
counter = 0  
for iteration_G in list(range(0,len(G))):
    for iteration_t in list(range(0,len(t))):
        
        matrix_1,matrix_2 = bunch of code


        tau, p_value = scipy.stats.kendalltau(matrix_1, matrix_2)
        results['tau'][counter] = tau
        results['p_value'][counter] = p_value
        results['G'][counter] = G[iteration_G]
        results['t_i'][counter] = G[iteration_t]
        counter = counter + 1
```

I would like to use the parfor equivalent in the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [parfor](https://pypi.org/project/parfor/). It is still a bit more complicated than MATLAB's parfor but it's pretty close to what I am used to.

```
t = list(range(1,16,1))
G = list(range(0,62,2))
for iteration_t in list(range(0,len(t))):
    @parfor(list(range(0,len(G))))
    def fun(iteration_G):
        result = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['tau', 'p_value'],index=range(0,1))

        matrix_1,matrix_2 = bunch of code   



        tau, p_value = scipy.stats.kendalltau(matrix_1, matrix_2)     
        result['tau'] = tau
        result['p_value'] = p_value
        fun = numpy.array([tau,p_value])
        return fun
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `parfor`, but you can use the joblib package to run functions in parallel.

In this simple example there's a function that prints its argument and we use `Parallel` to execute it multiple times in parallel with a for-loop

```
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


# function that you want to run in parallel
def foo(i):
    print(i)


# define the number of cores (this is how many processes wil run)
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

# execute the function in parallel - `return_list` is a list of the results of the function
# in this case it will just be a list of None's
return_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(foo)(i) for i in range(20))
```

If this doesn't work for what you want to do, you can try to use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html) - it might be a bit more difficult to set-up, but in theory with numba you can just add `@njit(parallel=True)` as a decorator to your function and numba will try to parallelise it for you.